# lodash check values where in two objects one by one

Tags: lodash

I have two objects, the first one like below:

raw: {item: 100, nested:{nested1: 20, nested2: 100}}

The second one has the same structure but provide some fixed value range:

range： {item: '20, 60', nested: {nested1: '20, 80', nested2: '30, 110'}}

I want to loop check every value in 'raw' if it in range of 'range', return a result like:

{item: false, nested: {nested1: true, nested2: true}}

```js
var range = {
  blood: {
    hemoglobin: '20, 50'
  },
  pulse: '20, 60'
}
var data = {
  blood: {
    hemoglobin: 30
  },
  pulse: 30
}

_.mixin({
  deeply: function(map) {
    return function(obj, fn) {
      return map(_.mapValues(obj, function(v) {
        if (_.isPlainObject(v)) {
          return _.deeply(map)(v, fn);
        } else if (_.isArray(v)) {
          return _.map(v, item => _.deeply(map)(item, fn));
        }
        return v;
      }), fn);
    }
  },
});

var obj = _.deeply(_.mapKeys)(data, function(val, key) {
  // ...
});
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) as a way to pair both the `data` object and `range` object and determine which values are contained within a range or not.

```
var result = _.mergeWith(_.cloneDeep(data), range, function(d, r) {
  if(!_.isObject(d)) {
    return _(r).split(',').map(_.trim).map(Number)
      .thru(_.spread(function(x, y) {
        return d >= x && d <= y;
      })).value();
  }
});
```

```js
var range = {
  blood: {
    hemoglobin: '20, 50'
  },
  pulse: '20, 60'
};

var data = {
  blood: {
    hemoglobin: 30
  },
  pulse: 30
};

var result = _.mergeWith(_.cloneDeep(data), range, function(d, r) {
  if(!_.isObject(d)) {
    return _(r).split(',').map(_.trim).map(Number)
      .thru(_.spread(function(x, y) {
        return d >= x && d <= y;
      })).value();
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```